# iOS Purchase local currency for app content

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, appstore-approval

I'm developing a chat application. I have a different content that users can buy. But $0.99 is too high price for it. I want to provide some local currency (diamonds / coins or something like that). For example, user can buy 100 coins for $0.99. Therefore, he can buy something with this 30 coins, then buy another one for 10 (for example).

Can I do it?
Of course I can (technically), but will I get the rejection from the AppStore later?

There is an application Line. For Android, it has its own internal currency. But for iOS,  purchase content only for real currency.

Comment: You can do this.
Lots of apps Uses this technique for motivating users for in-App Purchase. But all the updations  coin expenditure should take place on application level (and your server if you are using server).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this. Lots of apps Uses this technique for motivating users for in-App Purchase. But all the updations upon coin expenditure should take place on application level (and your server if you are using server)

And coins only purchased from in-App Purchase

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of apps that provide its own "currency", for example some games can sell you coins, and with this coins you can do some other things.

The only thing you have to be careful with is that those coins are only bought inside your app trough In-App purchase. If they are not, Apple will reject it.